# What font is this? (Used in publishing sheet music)

Tags: fonts, publishing

I have tried my best but have failed.  Asking for help identifying this font.

It is the font used for fingerings in very old books of sheet music.  Here is an example from a book published in 1976:

[image: Music Fingerings 1,2,3,4,5]

I have looked all over, coming closest with Century font, but either the 4 is different, or the bottom of the 2 is different.  I installed some music composition software, and the font it uses for fingerings is not even close.  I am hoping someone can recognize this font.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Free fat numeral font as used in sheet music time signatures?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/146896/free-fat-numeral-font-as-used-in-sheet-music-time-signatures)

Comment: No, unfortunately. I read that post before. One had the fat numbers but only for key signatures (one on top of the other), the other font mentioned I could not find a TTF file for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I owe this to Murphy's Law - once you ask for help you will immediately solve the problem.

I found what I need in the Maestro font.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not surprised you're having trouble. You're in the right place with Century: you're looking at a Didone, "rational" or "modern" typeface of the nineteenth century. The distinctive feature is the large ball terminals. However, this style of letter in sheet music is distinctive for being both very bold and having some quite specific number forms: open 4, 2 with a curled bottom. It's not common in most fonts. It's historically been quite common for specific industries to develop styles of lettering that are specific to them.

So your best bet is, as others have noted, a font specifically for music steeped in the traditions of the genre. But if you wanted a font in this genre but with a full character set, check out [Ingeborg from Typejockeys](https://typejockeys.com/font/ingeborg/styles) with its [decorative figures in bold](https://www.fontspring.com/tools/asset/jghqn5lxcbsa89nshrhrmo6ot35pbwzk/ingeborg_specimen.pdf) (not all software will support these), [Hoefler & Co's Surveyor](https://www.typography.com/fonts/surveyor/overview), or the same company's [Numbers series](https://www.typography.com/fonts/numbers/overview) (numbers only, hence the name).